# Can I test authentication with an RSA key locally?

Tags: ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

Is there a way to check locally if you're providing the correct passphrase to an RSA key?

I recently had trouble pushing some commits to github because the push prompted for a password and then failed authentication. I verified that github had the correct public key for the `id_rsa` file in my `~/.ssh` directory, and I verified that I could authenticate with Github (if you `ssh git@github.com` it will tell you you authenticated but that they don't offer shell access,) so I knew the problem was on my end, not Github's.

(I should point out that at this point I simply used `git format-patch` to get my commits as files, then blew away my working repository and re-cloned from Github, reapplied the patches using `git am`, and pushed without any trouble, so whatever the original problem was, it's fixed.)

This left me wondering, though: how would I know if an authentication problem with a remote host was me providing the wrong passphrase to my private key, or the remote host not recognizing my key? Is there a way to do a test authentication with the private key, locally, without trying to connect to a remote host?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run `ssh-add` to add your key to your current `ssh-agent`. This will prompt for your passphrase.

Normally, when `ssh-agent` is running, and you add a key to it, you won't have to unlock your key any more when you connect to hosts that recognise that key. If that isn't what you want, just run `ssh-add -d` to remove it off your `ssh-agent` when you're done testing.

Answer (score 46):

Or as pointed here:
[How can I test my ssh-keys locally without a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466539/how-can-i-test-my-ssh-keys-locally-without-a-server)

You can do this:

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

And this doesn't require any server (works great with msysgit on Windows).

Comment: I was totally confused, thinking that `-y` must mean "Yes to all" -- but it doesn't, and indeed it seems to do what it's supposed to.