# How can I test my ssh-keys locally without a server

Tags: windows, ssh, local

I want to test my keys in `~/.ssh`. I do not have `sshd` running (Git-Bash@Windows does not provide it). I'd like to test if I still remember the passphrase for my keys.

I found these answers [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891616/can-i-test-authentication-with-an-rsa-key-locally), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411457/how-do-i-verify-my-ssh-password), but they do not work for me.

Is there an easy way to verify my ssh keys without an ssh server?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should work:

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

Or to avoid filename prompt question:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f key_file
```

Comment: Thx! that worked like a charm. No funny software installs needed :) I love those pure command line tools.

Comment: And it works great on Windows with msysgit (which is not the case with the server based answers!).

Comment: Newb question - Where should this command be run on a Windows machine?

Comment: Git Bash would be the answer... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [SSHNet](http://sshnet.codeplex.com) and a bunch of code you can try to open your private key and check if provided password is correct.

```
PrivateKeyFile key = new PrivateKeyFile(keypath, passphrase);
```

Above code fails if passphrase is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I can't install any new uncommon software here.

Comment: @Juve: don't you have Visual Studio installed?